# merge.xts on specific columns over a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, merge, xts, quantmod

I have downloaded a lot of stock data and need to compare it to a relevant index. To do this I need to merge the time series data (adjusted closing price column only) before I start calculating my log returns.

I have tried doing it in the following way with a for loop: please note that I have downloaded all the data into separate environments because it is a lot of data with many stock tickers.

```
require(quantmod)
e<-new.env()
tickers<-c("GE","BMW.DE","NOVO-B.CO","1COV.DE")
getSymbols("^GSPC",from="2018-01-01")
getSymbols(tickers,from="2019-01-01",env=e)
```

Now I want to take the 6th column (adjusted closing price) of each element in environment e and apply merge.xts(join="inner") to the column to combine it with the adjusted closing price of GSPC. I choose join="inner" to make sure that I only have observations with matching xts dates.

```
for(ticker in tickers){
x<-get(ticker,envir=e)[,6]
merged_prices<-merge.xts(x,GSPC[,6])
}
```

I get an error when I try to do this, I have also tried to create a data frame before running the for loop but I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track by using an environment. Good job!

You want to extract the adjusted close column from each symbol and merge them into one xts object. You're on the right track with your `for` loop, but there's an easier way. You can loop over the elements in an environment using `lapply()`, and use the `Ad()` function to extract the adjusted close column.  Then use `do.call(merge, ...)` to call the `merge` function on the output of `lapply()`.

```r
merged_prices <- do.call(merge, lapply(e, Ad))
```

You can merge the adjusted close for GSPC at this point (`merge(Ad(GSPC), merged_prices)`), or you could include it in your list of tickers.

Comment: Hi Joushua, thanks a bunch. This works. One question though, since I am doing this for all 600 stocks from EUROSTOXX600 and the S&P500, when I merge the xts objects like you suggest above, I end up with a lot of NAs. I was thinking that using na.locf(fromLast=TRUE) on the merged object may be an idea or to use merge.xts(join="inner"), but then I run the risk of not having many observations in case one stock has next to no observations. What do you think? Thanks a bunch again, highly appreciated

Comment: It's hard to say what you should do about the NA without knowing more about the analysis you're working on. For example, using LOCF would be fine if you're going to use the price data to calculate indicators (e.g. moving averages). But if you're doing covariance-based portfolio optimization, you should omit the NA from the price data, then calculate returns, then the covariance matrix.

Comment: Well it's an event study so I guess omitting the NAs is the best option. Thanks a bunch again, appreciate it very much. I will become more familiar with the do.call() function :)